# Why when I convert a .py file to an .exe terminal based program, a print in a for loop isn't printing until the loop has ended?

Tags: python, for-loop, time, printing, sleep

I want to print a dot every second 60 times, when I run the application from the IDE, it works fine but when I convert the file to an exe, it doesn't print the dots until the for loop has ended.

This is the code:

```
import time

for i in range(60):
    print(".", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
```

*Sorry if it is a dumb question, I am new to python*

Comment: may be it is considering it "tab" and "space" as an issue?

Comment: have you tried with the flush argument? `print('.', flush=True)

Comment: also it seems you may be using the print as a progress bar? If that is true have a look at tqdm package!  https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `flush = True` to your print function.

The problem is likely buffering in the output of your program, which gets flushed traditionally when the printed content reaches a sufficient size, on newlines, and on exiting the program.

Manually adding the flush parameter will flush the output every time you call the print function. See [the print function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).